# Paramiko sed find and replace wont pass through

Tags: python, linux, bash, sed, paramiko

I am currently working on a script where when I launch an EC2 instance, I send a paramiko command to rename the host name. Because this is a custome AMI, I cannot use the AWS Boto3 CLI to do it, so I need to do it via an SSH command.

The problem I am running into, is Paramiko seems to fail at passing my specific command. It will pass other commands just fine, but I am assuming I am running into some sort of limitation of either paramiko or python and cannot seem to troubleshoot it. This is for a RHEL instance, so renaming the Network file is the only way I can think to do this.

If I run the command, as is, through the terminal of the host, it works. So something between paramiko and this command seems to be the blocker.

Here is my sample script t hat should work, but seems to fail at running the command.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import boto3
import time
import subprocess
import paramiko
import StringIO

c = paramiko.SSHClient()
c.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

c.connect(hostname = '12.34.56.78', username = "username", key_filename='''/Users/mallachar/Downloads/testkey.pem''' )
stdin , stdout, stderr = c.exec_command('sudo sed -i -E "s/^HOSTNAME.*/HOSTNAME=testhost.company/" /etc/sysconfig/network')

print stdout.read()
print stderr.read()

c.close
```

Here is me printing stdout and stderr

```
sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
```

Comment: Do you see an error message? Does the `stdout` or `stderr` contain anything? Can you run any command (like `echo`) and see something? Is sudo permissions correctly set? Are the double quotes in the exec command an issue, perhaps they need to be escaped?

Comment: @Pyrce here are the outputs I get when i do print.

`<paramiko.ChannelFile from <paramiko.Channel 0 (open) window=2097152 -> <paramiko.Transport at 0xc533310L (cipher aes128-ctr, 128 bits) (active; 1 open channel(s))>>>`

`<paramiko.ChannelFile from <paramiko.Channel 0 (open) window=2097152 -> <paramiko.Transport at 0xc533310L (cipher aes128-ctr, 128 bits) (active; 1 open channel(s))>>>`

`Out[16]: <bound method SSHClient.close of <paramiko.client.SSHClient object at 0x10c5331d0>>`

Comment: Those are the stdout and stderr messages? Those just look like you printed `c`

Comment: I updated the code to show what I did.

Comment: That's weird, because stdout should be from the command you passed in, not a python object print-out. Try some other other suggestions I listed -- I think you just need to spend some time debugging the command execution.

Comment: exec_command returns file-like objects.  I think you need to do stdout.read(), stderr.read()

Comment: You need to call `.read()` on the `stdout` and `stdin` objects to get the real data - they are file-like objects

Comment: Thanks @Ben, the error appears to be

`sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo`

Comment: why all the dicking about with abstracted bits of python? when a simple ssh -t -i /Users/mallachar/Downloads/testkey.pem username@12.34.56.78 "sudo sed ..." etc will do. (the -t to the ssh command allocates a psuedo terminal so sudo will work).

Comment: @Cwissy automate a function that does a lot of other things first. This script launches a bunch of EC2 instances, SSH into them to change the hostname, reports the information to me, and then the instances are put into production behind the ELB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple, I had to add this to the command.

```
get_pty=True
```

so

```
stdin , stdout, stderr = c.exec_command('sudo sed -i -E "s/^HOSTNAME.*/HOSTNAME=testhost.company/" /etc/sysconfig/network',get_pty=True)
```

Comment: It tells me I have to wait to accept my own. When i try to click it says

`You can accept your own answer in 23 hours`